# Changing html button with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Been trying to crack this for days and I think I've got tunnel vision that can't see past my mistake!

I have an HTML button which when calling a javascript method and passing it true or false I want the button class to change as well as the innerHTML. Currently, I can only get the class to change. See the code below:

```
var buttonHandler = function () {
  toggleButton(false);
  getRecords();
};

var btn = document.getElementById("get-records");
btn.addEventListener("click", buttonHandler);
```

JS:

```
function toggleButton (loaded) {
   btn.innerHTML = loaded ? "Get next" : "Loading...";
   btn.classList.toggle("button-not-loading");
   btn.classList.toggle("button-loading");
}
```

HTML (The button looks like this):

```
<button id="get-records" class="button-not-loading">Get next</button>
```

CSS:
    .button-loading { 
       background-color:dodgerblue; 
       color:white 
    }

```
.button-not-loading { 
   background-color:lawngreen; 
   color:white 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always pass `false` to your `toggleButton` function, thats why html is changed only once. You should change `true/false` also, just add variable which will hold this value:

```js
var loading = true;

var buttonHandler = function () {
  loading = !loading;
  toggleButton(loading);
  getRecords();
};


var btn = document.getElementById("get-records");
btn.addEventListener("click", buttonHandler);

function toggleButton (loaded) {
   btn.innerHTML = loaded ? "Get next" : "Loading...";
   btn.classList.toggle("button-not-loading");
   btn.classList.toggle("button-loading");
}
```

```css
.button-loading { background-color:dodgerblue; color:white }
.button-not-loading { background-color:lawngreen; color:white }
```

```html
<button id="get-records" class="button-not-loading">Get next</button>
```

Comment: Good answer! In practice, of course, make sure you name the global variables in a way that make sense. 'loading' is a very generic name that could conflict with other toggle buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `toggleButton(false);`

Use this `toggleButton(this.classList.contains('button-not-loading') ? false : true);`

Comment: I personally like this solution over the use of a global variable.